# Is there a windows equivelant of QFileinfo::Owner()?

Tags: c++, qt

I ask the above question as whenever I use this to determine the person who last saved a file it just returns a blank string. Am i doing it wrong or is there an equivalent library/method that will do this for me?

Forgot to add my code. It's simply.

```
QFileInfo fileName = it.fileInfo();
qDebug() << fileName.owner();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And here's what *Qt* says about **ownerId()** :

> ```
> uint QFileInfo::ownerId() const
> ```
>
> Returns the id of the owner of the
>   file.
>
> On Windows and on systems where files do not have owners this function
>   returns ((uint) -2).

Comment: I asked this a couple of years ago so I've worked an alternate way around the problem but this would have worked for what I needed so i'll mark it as solved. Thanks. :)

Comment: Yes, but someone today is having the same issue.. So, sharing is good :)

Comment: But Windows files do have owners.  File -> Properties -> Security -> Advanced -> Owner

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are doing sth wrong. For owner() function qt site says:

> QString QFileInfo::owner () const
>
> Returns the owner of the file. On systems where files do not have
>   owners, or if an error occurs, an empty string is returned.
>
> This function can be time consuming under Unix (in the order of
>   milliseconds).

This method should return account name for owner of the file. You have to do sth else to get the name who edited file last.

Edit: QFileInfo::lastModified () maybe useful for you.

Comment: I looked into the Last Modified method. It only provides you the date/time it was edited last but not who edited it.